# How to report negative binomial results with a multi-level categorical variable?

Tags: spss, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, poisson-binomial-distribution

I would like to ask 2 questions: the first, as indicated in the title, concerns how to report the results of the 'negative binomial model'. The second, differently, relates to how to interpret the output of the 'zero-inflated negative binomial' using SPSS.

*Question 1)* I will describe the concrete case: I want to know whether 3 different versions of the same advertising video (male voice-over, female voice-over, no voice-over) have an impact on the number of sales of the product. The three voice-over types are the 3 levels of my categorical independent variable, the number of product sales is my dependent count variable. When I conduct the negative binomial regression, the test naturally asks me to indicate the reference level: I select the male voice-over as reference level. The result of the test will be that the following comparisons will be made (the statistical significance of which will be indicated):

- female vs male voice-over
- no voice-over vs male voice-over

In this way, however, I have no way of knowing whether female voice-over is statistically significant compared to no voice-over. When reporting the results into a scientific article, can I change the reference level by putting no voice-over so that I also have the comparison between female voice-over and no voice-over? If possible, could I describe my results by saying, for example, that the male voice-over has more impact than the female voice-over, the female voice-over more than the non-voice-over, and the male voice-over more than the non-voice-over?

*Question 2)* In SPSS when I conduct a zero inflated negative binomial model the software gives me as output two coefficient tables called 'Count Model Coefficients' and 'Zero-Inflation Model Coefficients'. In both of these tables there is the same independent variable. Which of the two tables should I consider in order to understand if my independent variable is significant with respect to the zero inflated negative binomial model (sometimes I find that in the 'Count Model Coefficients' table the predictor is significant, while in the 'Zero-Inflation Model Coefficients' table it is not and vice versa)?

Thank you